# Bash Script To PowerShell

Tags: bash, powershell, curl

What does this mean in Bash ?

```
 INFO=$(curl_with_log -F "sub=upload" \ -F "filecontent=@$FILE;filename=$DESTFILE" \ -F "login=$USER" -F "password=$PASSWORD" "$UPLOAD_URL") || return
```

Im trying to do the exact same thing in powershell, i got it for the most part, i just need to know what this section is doing.

```
\ -F "filecontent=@$FILE;filename=$DESTFILE" \
```

I think there is something funky going on with the @$ but im not sure what its actually doing.

Comment: The backslashes are likely unnecessary. It looks like you took something that was split across multiple lines and joined it back into one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing funky is going on, the `@` is not interpreted by bash  at all.

```
themel@kallisti: ~ $ FILE=foo
themel@kallisti: ~ $ echo @$FILE
@foo
```

This is most likely interpreted by curl, where `@somewhere` usually means "[contents of file `somehwere`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F)".

Answer (score 1):

For a full list of Curl options, check out this site: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Under -F you'll find this:

> You can also explicitly change the name field of a file upload part by setting filename=, like this:
>
> `curl -F "file=@localfile;filename=nameinpost" url.com`